# How to set div position from relative to fixed in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, fixed, sticky

Here is my initial HTML structure (I used Bootstrap framework)

```
<html>
<body>
    <header>My header</div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="list" class="col-md-7"></div>
            <div id="map" class="col-md-5"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <footer>My Header</footer>
</body>
```

And the css :

```
#list
{
    height : 2500px /* For the exemple */
}

#map
{
    height : 500px
}

#map.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Initially my position of div #map is **relative**.

I would like to set position of div #map to **fixed** when the div (#map) becomes visible on the screen until the bottom of div #list.

And finally, I would like to set my div to **relative** position again when my div #map reached the bottom of div #list.

For this scenario, I used the affix plugin of bootstrap :

```
$('#map').affix({
        offset: { top:  $('#map').offset().top }
    });
```

BUT when my scroll reaches the div #map, it disappears from the screen (because position is fixed and the width of my div#map is liquid)

How to display the div #map with the fixed position on the top/right off the screen ans with my initially size (when it'is in position:relative) ?

Is someone a solution to this problem ? Thanks you for your help !

Here is my desired scenario :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/b43hj/3503/

```
<header>My Header</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">   
      <div id="list"></div>
      <div id="theFixed">SOMETHING</div>
   </div>
</div>
<footer>My Footer</footer>

#theFixed {
height : 300px;
background: red;
position: fixed;
top: 700px;
right: 0px;
width: 40%;  
}
#list {
  height: 2500px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#theFixed").css("top",Math.max(0,700-$(this).scrollTop()));
});
```